# Asynchronous set in XMemcached

Tags: java, performance, asynchronous, memcached, xmemcached

I have to fill a Memcached server with a lot of entries using XMemcached.

As Memcached (and XMemcached) doesn't support multi-set, is there a way to "set" a value without waiting for the request to complete?

Maybe that is the case natively with XMemcached? I didn't find informations about this in its documentation.

Comment: Memcached does support multi-sets, but XMemcached might not support them. A multi-set is just a set followed by a bunch of setq's and then a no-op. The no-op will trigger memcached to only return responses for the sets that have erred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the setWithNoReply method which supported by xmemcached client